# Can you "teach" computers to do algebra using variable expressions (eg aX+bX=(a+b)X)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Let's say in the example lower case is constant and upper case is variable.

I'd like to have programs that can "intelligently" do specified tasks like algebra, but teaching the program new methods should be easy using symbols understood by humans. For example if the program told these facts:

aX+bX=(a+b)X

if a=bX then X=a/b

Then it should be able to perform these operations:
2a+3a=5a

3x+3x=6x

3x=1   therefore x=1/3

4x+2x=1 -> 6x=1 therefore x= 1/6

I was trying to do similar things with Prolog as it can easily "understand" variables, but then I had too many complications, mainly because two describing a relationship both ways results in a crash. (not easy to sort out)

To summarise: I want to know if a program which can be taught algebra by using mathematic symbols only. I'd like to know if other people have tried this and how complicated it is expected to be. The purpose of this is to make programming easier (runtime is not so important)

Comment: The short answer is "Yes".

The problem is that I am not qualified enough to explain you exactly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want machine to do and how intelligent it should be.

Your question is mostly about AI but not ML. AI deals with formalization of "human" tasks while ML (though being a subset of AI) is about building models from data.

Described program may be implemented like this:

Each fact form a pattern. Program given with an expression and some patterns can try to apply some of them to expression and see what happens. If you want your program to be able to, for example, solve quadratic equations given rule like `ax² + bx + c = 0 → x = (-b ± sqrt(b²-4ac))/(2a)` then it'd be designed as follows:

Somebody gives a set of rules. Rule consists of a pattern and an outcome (solution or equivalent form). Think about the pattern as kind of a regular expression.

Then the program is asked to show some intelligence and prove its knowledge via doing something with a given expression. Here comes the major part:

- you build a graph of expressions by applying possible rules (if a pattern is applicable to an expression you add new vertex with the corresponding outcome).
- Then you run some path-search algorithm (A*, for example) to find sequence of transformations leading to the form like `x = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting question, although it off topic in SO (tool recommendation)

But nevertheless, because it captured my imagination, I wrote couple of function using [R](http://cran.r-project.org/) that can solve stuff like that quite easily

First, you'll have to install R, after words you'll need to download package called [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf)

So in R console run

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
```

And then you can define the following functions that I wrote

```
FirstFunc <- function(temp){
paste0(eval(parse(text = gsub("[A-Z]", "", temp))), unique(str_extract_all(temp, "[A-Z]")[[1]]))
}

SecondFunc <- function(temp){
 eval(parse(text = strsplit(temp, "=")[[1]][2])) / eval(parse(text = gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", strsplit(temp, "=")[[1]][1])))
}
```

Now, the first function will solve equations like

> aX+bX=(a+b)X

While the second will solve equations like

> 4x+2x=1

For example

```
FirstFunc("3X+6X-2X-3X")
```

will return

```
"4X"
```

Now this functions is pretty primitive (mostly for the propose of illustration) and will solve equation that contain only one variable type, something like `FirstFunc("3X-2X-2Y")` won't give the correct result (but the function could be easily modified)

The second function will solve stuff like

```
SecondFunc("4x-2x=1")
```

will return

```
0.5
```

or

```
SecondFunc("4x+2x*3x=1")
```

will return

```
0.1
```

Note that this function also works only for one unknown variable (`x`) but could be easily modified too